# Match exact word in string ruby regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I have this string in ruby and I'm trying to make a match for sin

```
"please don't share this: 234-604-142"
"please don't share this: 234-604-1421"
```

so far I have

```
\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{3}
```

but this will also match the second case. Adding a ^ and $ for begins and ends will cause this not to function at all.

To fix this I could do this:

```
x = "please don't share this: 234-604-1421"
x.split.last ~= /^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{3}$/
```

but is there a way to match the sin otherwise?

Comment: try `/\b\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{3}\b/`

Comment: Will you *ALWAYS* have phone numbers in that format? Phone numbers change depending on the country, and they're not all in a U.S. format. See "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation".

Comment: This is for a sin card not a phone number if you read the very first line..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option worth considering for your rule is

```
(?<!\d)\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{3}(?!\d)
```

That way, if for any reason your phone number is followed or preceded by letters, as in

```
"please don't share this number234-604-142because it's private"
```

the regex will still work.

**Explain Regex**

```
(?<!                     # look behind to see if there is not:
  \d                     #   digits (0-9)
)                        # end of look-behind
\d{3}                    # digits (0-9) (3 times)
-                        # '-'
\d{3}                    # digits (0-9) (3 times)
-                        # '-'
\d{3}                    # digits (0-9) (3 times)
(?!                      # look ahead to see if there is not:
  \d                     #   digits (0-9)
)                        # end of look-ahead
```

Comment: I like this but I'm a tad confused. So its checking to see if there are not numbers ahead?

Comment: Yes, it checks that after the final three digits, there is not another digit.

Comment: I think the goal is to *not* match phone numbers.

Comment: well yeah but the regex is still valid since its for a sin ;)

Comment: Note that if you wanted the same thing at the front of the number, as in `please don't share this number234-604-142because it's private` but not `"please don't share this number3234-604-142because it's private"`, we'd have to use a different strategy because JS doesn't support lookbehind.

Comment: ah so i would need that as well what would I use to make that work

Comment: @Snowfiring, `the regex is still valid since its for a sin` ... *sin: an immoral act considered to be a transgression against divine law.*

Comment: In that situation, a workaround is to match one extra character in front of the first three digits (or none if we are at the beginning of the line, in m mode): `(?:^|\D)(\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{3})(?!\d)`, and to capture the digits to Group 1, as the parentheses do here. Your match is contained in Group 1.

Comment: It's a pleasure. Added sample code for that at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: @zx81 It's ruby not javascript =)

Comment: Please see updated answer... For some reason I thought it was JS not Ruby (as @hwnd pointed out) so we can use lookbehind at the front, same recipe as the back. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @hwnd Man you're right, why did I think it was JS!... :) Alright that's easy to fix.

Comment: @hwnd What, you mean it can happen to you?... :) :)